# Whats the best way to read ext4 partitions in windows 10 (in the year 2022)?

Tags: windows-10, ext4

There's plenty of articles out there (and questions/answers here on superuser) of how to do this, but I can't find any that aren't outdated.

Comment: I had a similar question, DiskInternals Linux Reader  is still the best way to go in 2022.